# SQL Query two fetch multiple table data by a conditional of an table

Tags: postgresql

I have four table sa, at, ar, lv,

Sa table consist

```
|Name|
|s1|
|s2|
|s3|
```

at table consist

```
|Name|
|t1|
|t2|
|t3|
```

ar table consist

```
|Name|
|r1|
|r2|
|r3|
```

lv table consust

```
|Name|
|l1|
|l2|
|l3|
```

Now I have 2 tables pf, pfs

pf table consist

```
|sa| at| ar| lv
|s1| t1| r1| l1|
```

Now if pf table has any value 'All' then it will update all combination of others table data into pfs

like sa has 'All'

```
  |sa| at| ar| lv|
  |All| t1| r1| l1
```

Then pfs table should have

```
  |sa| at |ar| lv|
  |s1| t1| r1| l1|
  |s2| t1 | r1| l1|
  |s3| t1| r1| l1|
```

in this way if pf consist `sa = 'All'` and `at = 'All'` then all combination of `s1,s2,s3` and `t1,t2,t3`  into pfs

Can you please advise me how can I do it more elegant way?

I know I need to write a trigger on pf .

Any hep will really be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query:

```
select 
    coalesce(sa.name, sa) as sa,
    coalesce(at.name, at) as at,
    coalesce(ar.name, ar) as ar,
    coalesce(lv.name, lv) as lv
from pf
left join sa on pf.sa = 'All'
left join at on pf.at = 'All'
left join ar on pf.ar = 'All'
left join lv on pf.lv = 'All';
```

returns expected combinations. Use it in a trigger or as standalone query, according to your needs.